# Is there a name/study for "connecting" vectors? (not addition)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

Is there a name/study for this kind of thing?

Edit: I'm not looking for vector addition -- the origins of each arrow should be preserved

The idea is that the vectors are combined so that the end of one vector is the origin of the next vector (all go in the same direction). I'm not that familiar with linear algebra but wanted to learn more about work that's been done on this kind of stuff.

I'm specifically wondering if there's a generalized notion for this kind of thing from abstract algebra.

Comment: As in - the *sum* of vectors?

Comment: Is that the same thing? to me it looks like a way to create a new vector by adding two vectors together and forgetting one of the origins:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html

That was one of the first things I saw but it's not what I'm looking for -- what I want is more about preserving the original vectors (and origins) and studying it as is.

Comment: @risto It is the same thing. See [these](https://drmenguin.com/files/la.pdf#lemma.1.3) notes.

Comment: Vector addition doesn't preserve all of the origins. In the link I gave, vector addition doesn't preserve the origin that's in between (origin of vector B on the left side and origin of vector A on the right side).

Comment: @risto I guess what he is asking that vector representation does not have any information on where it lies in the vector space since translation does not affect the vectors. I think the question is that do we have a representation where a vector translated to a different point has a different representation.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something like a piecewise-linear continuous map of vectors. I'm not sure if there's any work that's done of that sort of thing:  

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function

Comment: Do you mean something like treating vectors as paths, and making a concatenation of paths?

Comment: Yeah, like directed paths. I looked into graph theory and something like weighted directed acyclic graphs and signal flow graphs (this would be used for comp sci work) but I think that would lose some of the information like it's coordinates

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is; it is called addition.

Every vector space by definition has two operations associated with it: Addition of vectors, which is just what you have described, and stretching a vector by a number (i.e. increasing the length by a factor while keeping the same direction).

If you want to learn more about this, you should get familiar with the abstract definitions of groups, fields, and vector spaces (maybe also take a look at inner products). Greetings,

Intergalakti